# Python3 Indentation of return values

Tags: python, function

FIND 33:

Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to 
a 3 somewhere.

```
has_33([1, 3, 3]) → True
has_33([1, 3, 1, 3]) → False
has_33([3, 1, 3]) → False
```

This is how I did:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
        else:    
            return False
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
The answer was:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Why is the first method of code won't work? Can someone explain?

Comment: Your first variant dies not loop through the numbers - it always returns in the first step.

Comment: when you `return`, your function exits and control flow is returned back to the caller. So if ever there are no 2 consecutive `3`s in a row, you're going to exit your function, and not check the rest of your array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        print("iteration ",i)
        if nums[i] == 3 and nums[i+1] == 3:
            return True
        else:    
            return False
```

So in the above code if you see the code returns from the `else` part. Also, the loop in executes just once.

And what you want is, loop should run for complete length so need you to return  `False` at last.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your example, the first time it doesn't find a 3 next to another 3 returns False. And you want to wait to return False until it has checked all the list.